# ObjC: cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

How can I change the following code to be compatible with ARC:

```
MyObj* fn = nil;
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(popSomething:) withObject:(id)&fn waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Right now, I get the following error:

`error: cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to '__strong id' is disallowed with ARC [4]`

Comment: why can't you use `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(queuedFileNamesPop:) withObject:fn waitUntilDone:YES];` instead?

Comment: @AndreyZ: Because then, `fn` is still `nil` after the return of this call.

Comment: @Albert: that's because fn started out as `nil`.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Yes, and by passing `&fn`, the called function can actually override it (and that is what I want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the argument should be `(id *)`, ie. a pointer to an object, not an object.

But if you just want to return a value from a method that you need to execute on the main thread, a nicer solution is to use blocks and GCD:

```
__block id poppedFilename;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     poppedFilename = [self popFilename];
});
// do something with the popped file
```

This executes the method `-popFilename` on the main thread, and stores the result in `poppedFilename`. You must be careful not to call this method on the main thread, as it would deadlock. If you aren't sure if you are on the main thread, you could use something like this:

```
__block id poppedFilename;
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
     poppedFilename = [self popFilename];
} else {
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         poppedFilename = [self popFilename];
     });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting the main thread to update the string, then a better way to do it would be to use a mutable string and simply pass it to the main thread:

```
NSMutableString* fn = [NSMutableString string];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(queuedFileNamesPop:) withObject:fn waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Then the main thread can simply update the string.

Comment: Why would that be a better way? Is there no way I can somehow pass an object from the called function (`queuedFileNamesPop`) to the callee? This solution works now in case of a `NSString`. What if I want to pass some other object where there is no mutable class available?

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread doesn't give you any option for returning an object, so you have to pass in a place for it to put the return value.  Another option would be to pass an NSMutableArray and have the callee put whatever it wants into the array.

Comment: Yes, I thought about something like using a `NSMutableArray`. But I wasn't sure, that looked too much like a hack for me. Is that the common way to do this?

Comment: (Btw., I updated my question. I really don't want the question to be specific about `NSString`.)