# Crash in ScreenSaver since OSX 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, screensaver

Since OSX 10.8, I am getting a crash in my screensaver:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff94749790 objc_msgSend_vtable13 + 16
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9508941f -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 163
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff950892f8 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 131
3   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x000000010f6e64c7 -[PictureSliderView nextFileName] + 71 (PictureSliderView.m:69)
4   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x000000010f6e6675 -[PictureSliderView loadNext] + 53 (PictureSliderView.m:86)
5   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x000000010f6e695f -[PictureSliderView initWithFrame:isPreview:] + 447 (PictureSliderView.m:116)
6   com.apple.ScreenSaver           0x00007fff968c7cb5 -[ScreenSaverModules loadModule:frame:isPreview:] + 968
```

The related code:

```
- (void) queuedFileNamesPop:(NSString**)fn {
    if([queuedFileNames count] > 0) {
        *fn = [queuedFileNames objectAtIndex:0];
        [queuedFileNames removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}

- (NSString*) nextFileName
{
    NSString* fn = nil;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(queuedFileNamesPop:) withObject:(id)&fn waitUntilDone:YES];
    if(!fn) {
        [nextFileNameLock lock];
        fn = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:FileQueue_getNextFile()];
        [nextFileNameLock unlock];
    }
    return fn;
}
```

It seems to crash on `performSelectorOnMainThread` but I don't really see why. Is there something obvious which I am doing wrong?

Also, it only crashes if it is run from the ScreenSaverEngine. I have also a small dummy app which uses the same view to test the screensaver and it doesn't crashes there.

---

Edit: I asked about something very related (the same code) a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491149/objc-cast-of-an-indirect-pointer-to-an-objective-c-pointer). I wonder why I haven't taken one of those solutions in the end...

---

Edit: After the code change suggested by Jonathan, this crash does not occur anymore. However, at other events, I am getting other crashes, with this backtrace:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f9aefe8 CFRelease + 248
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f9d6770 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 400
2   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x0000000108c54425 -[PictureSliderView queuedFileNamesPop:] + 197 (PictureSliderView.m:64)
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff95089450 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 212
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff950892f8 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 131
5   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x0000000108c544b0 -[PictureSliderView nextFileName] + 128 (PictureSliderView.m:71)
6   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x0000000108c54665 -[PictureSliderView loadNext] + 53 (PictureSliderView.m:88)
7   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x0000000108c54cce -[PictureSliderView keyDown:] + 382 (PictureSliderView.m:178)
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff924ad8e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 9687
```

Or this:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff947497d0 objc_msgSend_vtable14 + 16
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f9aef9a CFRelease + 170
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8f9d6770 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 400
3   albertzeyer.PictureSlider       0x00000001023fac51 -[PictureSliderView keyDown:] + 257 (PictureSliderView.m:172)
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff924ad8e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 9687
```

I'm not sure yet wether they are related or independent.

Edit: They were not related. They were because of another additional `[fn release]` somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting a non-object to an object. This is probably conflicting with memory management changes in the Objective-C runtime or in Foundation (looks like they may have started building `NSObject` with ARC enabled.)

Instead of `(id)&fn`, try this:

```
NSValue *fnHandle = [NSValue valueWithPointer: &fn];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(queuedFileNamesPop:) withObject: fnHandle waitUntilDone: YES];
```

This passes the address of `fn` wrapped in an object. Then, in the called method:

```
- (void)queuedFileNamesPop: (NSValue *)fnHandle {
    NSString **fn = [fnHandle pointerValue];
    if (fn) {
        // existing code here
    }
}
```

This ensures that correct memory management is always followed.

Comment: Doesn't Apple do what Albert is doing with NSError?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I still have some other crashes at some other events -- they also seem to be related to changed memory management.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer: They pass by reference, yes (and that's still allowed!), but they never cast `NSError **` to `id` in order to pass it. You'd see the same crash if you used `-performSelector:withObject:` where the argument was an `NSError **`, because that method expects the parameter to be an object.

Comment: @Albert: If the answer helped, you should accept the answer. This tells other users who encounter the same problem that this is the correct solution. It also gives me 15 Internet Points.

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if the answer was correct because of the other crashes which I haven't fixed yet. Maybe the ARC with NSValue passed to another thread still messes something up or so.

Comment: You haven't described the other crashes. Nobody here can help solve them if we don't know what they are.

Comment: I haven't described them because I wasn't sure if they are related. But I'll just add them to the question.

Comment: They look very similar. What's the code look like in `-[PictureSliderView keyDown:]`? As for `-[PictureSliderView queuedFileNamesPop:]`, try using `[[*fn retain] autorelease]` before removing the object from the array.